# term for obvious "stuttering" in print

Tags: terminology, redundancy, typographical-errors

Is there a name for an obviously erroneous duplication of a word in a print medium? For example (with apologies to Mr. Lincoln)" "Four-score and seven seven years ago..."
If someone is relatively certain there isn't one, can you suggest a suitable short "title" for a list of such cases?

Comment: Generally speaking, this is called a "typo" (short for "typographical error").

Comment: In textual criticism this is called a *dittography*, but you may not want so technical a term.

Comment: I can't find any formal word, but there's a discussion on Google groups about it. They are calling it "Intentional Word Repetition" or (variant) "Faux Hesitation" when only parts of words are repeated. Didn't Poe maybe use word repetition for emphasis or effect?

Answer (score 1):

As StoneyB writes, this is a *dittography*, Oxford dictionary says:

> A mistaken repetition of a letter, word, or phrase by a copyist.
>
> Origin:
>      Late 19th century: from Greek dittos ‘double’ + -graphy.

It is not clear how technical a description you want, you should give a little more details of the context in which you'll refer to these typos. You could use 'List of dittographies', or 'List of erroneous repetitions'.

Comment: I intend to make a list & try to estimate what a proper correction would be if the context supports one.

Comment: @CEUser: so it is a quite technical usage? If you want to distinguish these erroneous repetitions from other typos, then you could use 'List of dittographies'